# How can I add thumbnail with content?

Tags: next.js, google-forms

I want to know about adding thumbnail with content.
For example, Google form list!

[image: Google forms screenshot]

I want to add thumbnail in content list with actual content screenshot.

I use Next.js and Typescript.
Please share solution

I couldn't even implement it because I couldn't think of a solution at all.
Please help me!